# How to interpolate holes in smooth image in opencv?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, interpolation

I have pretty *smooth* image with different light conditions:

[image]
And I need to fill holes correctly. **Edited:** <s>I'm going to use *bilinear interpolation*. But how to *properly* use it in this case?</s>

What *interpolaion method* is best suited and how to *properly* use it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to fill the black pixels ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes, all black areas

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use bilinear interpolation here as the changes are not monotonous.

I would rather use a global quadratic model for the three RGB components independently.

For the fitting (least-squares), you can take all non-black pixels, though sampling on a more or less dense grid should be enough.

Beware that there is also some saturation in the white, you should also ignore the saturated pixels (you will saturate the values *after* reconstruction).

Comment: under the assumption that a flat sheet is illuminated by a point source of light, which model will more accurately describe its brightness?

Comment: And what c++ lib you can recommend?

Comment: @victor1234: none. If I was to do it, I would program it myself.